# WordPress - remove action defined within plugin class with parameters

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I`m trying to remove these action

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array($this, 'renderOneClickOrderBtn'),35 );
```

defined in plugin (part of the code is pasted below)

I have tried these and it doesn't help

```
global $Frontend;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $Frontend, 'renderOneClickOrderBtn' ), 35 );
```

This is the part of the code from plugin:

```
class Frontend
{
    /**
     * @var FileManager
     */
    private $fileManager;

/**
 * Frontend constructor.
 *
 * @param FileManager $fileManager
 */
public function __construct(FileManager $fileManager)
{
    $this->fileManager = $fileManager;
    $options           = get_option(OneClickOrderPlugin::SLUG, array());

    if (! empty($options['displayOnCatalog'])) {
        add_action(
            'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',
            array($this, 'renderOneClickOrderBtn'),
            35
        );
    }

    add_action(
        'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
        array($this, 'renderOneClickOrderBtn'),
        35
    );

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'oneclickorder-script',
            $this->fileManager->locateAsset('frontend/js/premmerce-oneclickorder.js'),
            array('jquery-blockui')
        );
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'magnific-popup',
            $this->fileManager->locateAsset('frontend/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js')
        );
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'magnific-popup',
            $this->fileManager->locateAsset('frontend/css/magnific-popup.css')
        );
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'oneclickorder-style',
            $this->fileManager->locateAsset('frontend/css/premmerce-oneclickorder.css')
        );
    });

    $this->hooks();
}
```

I`ll appreciate any help, because there is no support from Premmerce plugin developers (

Comment: check the Frontend class object.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if i understand you. Maybe you can share some examples?

Comment: object already created somewhere like `$Frontend = new Frontend()`. check this

Comment: `global $Frontend;` is not correct object